# Is there a way to subdivide the face in one direction?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say I have a rectangular plane:

[image]

How to subdivide it in one direction, like I'm adding loop cuts:

[image]

My goal is to make something like this at the end, there each face is extruded up and flattened by Z axis:

[image]

So this plane is a part of a complex shape, I can't just replace it by  *Mesh Grid* primitive:

[image]

Thanks to @quellenform I created a solution based on his answer. Here is the final solution, for unlimited number of planes:

[image]

Comment: Go into Edge mode. Select opposing edges. Right-click and select Subdivide. Set the number of subdivisions you need in the bottom left properties panel. Job done.

Comment: @JohnEason do you see the **geometry-nodes** tag?

Comment: To be honest I didn't but the 'normal' solution seemed so simple that I commented anyway. :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

- First, convert your mesh to curves
- Then separate the sides/rails
- Divide them into the number of levels you want
- Create a grid
- Transfer the positions of the original points, discarding the *Z-axis*.
- Extrude the individual faces of the grid to the height of the rails

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

---

**Update**

Unfortunately, since you are using a complex mesh as a base, you cannot use the solution shown above.

But you would have the additional possibility to extend only the upper surface with steps and to put them on top of your object:

[image]

Comment: But there may be holes in the face: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llUPW.png , so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Crantisz I understand. But you would still have the possibility to extend the mesh upwards (see update).

Comment: It looks promising, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is somewhat similar to:

[How to subdivide a selection of faces in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274918/60486)

And the answer is you can't... What you can do is subdivide, then transfer data from one side to the created loops parallel to that side, then move those loops to overlap that side (verts have to overlap) and merge by distance. If you don't transfer the attributes, merge by distance may keep the vertices with interpolated values and remove those that were originally in place:

[image]

And subdivision nodes don't allow you to specify the number of cuts, it's iterations... So what really is your best bet is to create a plane with a correct topology, move it into place, transfer attributes, remove the former geometry and merge by distance.