# How to create gradual face subdivide effect with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using 3.4.1 build, I want to create an effect that slowly adds geometry to the mesh, in the same way Subdivide node does to the whole mesh, but not in an **integer** way, but in **float**, so that in wireframe mode you can visualize the new branches of subdivision appearing from the edges and vertices.

Here is an idea of what I am trying to achieve.  Note that the geometry starts to multiply as its zoom in (from 11:00 on).  I want to do that without necessarily zooming in.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRrBnI5L0u8

I want the subdivision to run slowly, to be able to subdivide it so I can see the new subdivisions running thru the mesh, as it increases (in a wireframe model, for instance).

I want to be able to animate the subdivision, not from 1 to 2, but having (1,2)then (1,5) and then (1,8) before complete 2 times subdiv. as Markus did in his video, but in Wireframe mode.

Or maybe it would be possible to achieve without even needing subdivision.  Transforming edges into curves and applying some sort of controlled triangulations, instead of the real mesh.
[image: before subdiv]

[image: after subdiv]

[image: The subdiv only allows "integers" and cannot be animated]

The subdiv only allows "integers" and cannot be animated

Comment: Could you please sketch the desired result? ...I honestly don't understand how this should look.

Comment: In my mind, I visualize, in the simplest sense, a 3x3 grid, like a "tic tac toe" board. When subdivision level is increased by 1 (representing zooming in, for example), the result is that the 4 corner squares are subdivided 3 times, the top, bottom, left, and right squares get subdivided 2 times, and the "center" of the board gets subdivided 1 time. (or possibly the inverse of this). Is that kind of what you're talking about?

Comment: Something like this? https://streamable.com/a20gob

Comment: It seems this is mostly a duplicate of [How to subdivide a selection of faces in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274918/60486) then just come up with a way to select faces in an animated way, e.g. from top to bottom or using boolean random with animated probability.

Comment: Not quite Markus,  This "selective" subdivision still does not allows me to gradually subdivide between 2 to 3 subdivisions (for instance).
In this case, I don't mind to subdivide the whole mesh, but it must go gradually between  1 to 2, 2 to 3, and so on...

Comment: Once you can subdivide selectively, you can just subdivide it with any level of subdivision, while subdividing other selections with a different level. Not saying the algorithm in the linked answer helps, because it changes the shape of subdivision, but the question is relevant. One more thing that would have to be implemented is taking the created edges and making them appear (scale from 0) slowly, or slide from existing edges.

Comment: "(...)One more thing that would have to be implemented is taking the created edges and making them appear (scale from 0) slowly, or slide from existing edges.(...)"
That's exactly what I want.  Is it possible?