# Creating knurl on certain faces using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

Creating knurl on certain faces using geometry nodes for **3D printing**.

I know I can create a knurl in "normal" Blender.

[image: knurl]

[Easy way to model spiral engraving (knurling) that is usually used on metal for better grip?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116466/easy-way-to-model-spiral-engraving-knurling-that-is-usually-used-on-metal-for)

But I'm trying to create a knurl on certain faces (**Example: Face 0 and 3 see red arrow**).

I was thinking of using triangulate with subdivide (but we still can't subdivide certain faces easily) [How to subdivide a selection of faces in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274918/).  Then I would extrude the vertices to have them poke out.

[image: img1]

**Any thoughts of creating a knurl and attaching it to certain faces using geometry nodes?**

Attached file below.

[image]

PS: I'm using Blender 3.5.1 and this will be 3D printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Triangulate the mesh in a checkerboard pattern to get an alternation of slanted edges that form rhombuses. And then move the vertices in the centers of the diamond along the normal upwards.
[image]

Result:
[image]

Download:
[image]

Comment: Late comment, but a summary of the strategy expressed in the nodes would really improve this (nice)  answer.